# Vaadin 21: "Assertion error: No child node found with id -1" when opening a link in new browser tab

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin21

In a Vaadin 21.0.1 application there are some `Tab`s with a `RouterLink` in each `Tab` for application navigation.

In general this works fine. But when I right-click at one of these `Tab`s / `RouterLink`s then a new (empty) browser tab opens and this error occurs: `Assertion error: No child node found with id -1`.

[image]

In Vaadin 20.0.9 the new tab also stays empty.

Has anybody an idea how to handle / fix this?

Comment: You need to provide some more information or preferably an example project that can be tested. It does sound similar to https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5830 which was about using the wrong scope

Comment: Yes, using `@UIScope` instead of `@VaadinSessionScope` made the difference. Thank you!